# use powershell to select all nested subdirectories which both contain and do not contain a specific file

Tags: powershell, batch

I am unable to return a list of (many) nested folders based on conditionals, and have tried for hours many different methods from searching online in documentation and sites such as this one.

I am trying the following line:

```ps
gci -recur -dir | ? { !(gci $_ -file -recur -filter √.txt) -and (gci $_ -file -recur -filter *.mp3) } | select name
```

and expecting to return a list of folders, which meet the following two conditions: contains at least one .mp3 file as a direct child, but does not contain a file named "√.txt"--as a direct child, i.e.:

-music
--artist
---album
----song1.mp3
would return just the album directory name or path, whereas:
-music
--artist
---album
----√.txt
----song1.mp3
would be skipped over, repeated for about 10 thousand variously nested albums.

Even more simply, I expect the following code to return a list of subdirectories which contain (as direct children) 1 or more .mp3 files, but it does not:

```ps
gci -recur -dir | ? { (gci $_ -file -recur -filter *.mp3) } | select name
```

It only returns the direct children (which are category folders such as "rock" or "jazz") of the current directory, despite the call to -recur.

What I would like to happen is I search a folder "music" which has many thousands of nested subdirectories, and return a list of the subdirectories (no matter how nested) which simultaneously contain (as direct children) mp3s but do not contain "√.txt" (as a direct child).

Hopefully this makes enough sense! Let me know if more info or clarity is needed.

Here is a snippet of the folder structure:

Directory: D:\music\rock\90s\Stereolab\albums:
1992 - Peng!
1992 - Switched On
1994 - Mars Audiac Quintet

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a folder structure example?

Comment: There is no way yo do it in just one command. What you would do is create a list of all the folders that contain at least one mp3, and then do a second loop with just that list and see if that folder contains your file. If so, remove that entry from the list.

Comment: this actually worked in one command: 
`gci -LiteralPath "D:\Music" -filter *.mp3 -recur | select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName | Get-Unique | ? { !(gci -LiteralPath $_ -filter √.txt -file) }` 
though I much prefer yours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way yo do it in just one command. What you would do is create a list of all the folders that contain at least one mp3, and then do a second loop with just that list and see if that folder contains your file. If so, remove that entry from the list.

Here is an example script of what this be:

```
$targetFolder = "C:\Test"

# Step 1: Scan the target folder and its subfolders for MP3 files
$mp3Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $targetFolder -Filter "*.mp3" -Recurse `
          | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory | Get-Unique

# Step 2: Filter the list to exclude folders containing 'v.txt'
$filteredFolders = $mp3Files | Where-Object {
    $vTxtFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter "v.txt" -File `
              -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    -not $vTxtFile
}

# Step 3: Output the resulting folders
$filteredFolders
```

Comment: It worked! You're amazing, thank you so much! I also learned a lot about PS in the process.

Comment: You're welcome. :)